# Burger Menu Placement in Flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, flexbox

I want to build a little note taking app but i cant figure out how i can put a burger menu on the right side of the flexbox. Down here you can find my js and css file:

**JavaScript / HTML**

```
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <main className={styles.content}>
            <div className={styles.templatelist}>
                <div className={styles.template}>
                    <h2>Daily Meeting Minutes</h2>
                    <div className={styles.properties}>
                        <p>Sections: 5</p>
                        <p>Questions: 5</p>
                        <p>Tables: 5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
      </div>
```

I have tried to create a new div and position it with top and left but nothing seems to work for me.

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}


.templatelist {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.template {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(13.3px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(13.3px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,153,0, .5);
}

.properties {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    gap: 2rem;
}
```

**Codepen**
https://codepen.io/Vylex/pen/ZERgxzm

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkr3v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.template {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(13.3px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(13.3px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,153,0, .5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.properties {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

p {
    margin: .5rem;
}
```

Comment: Not quite that what i wanted, but thanks to your code i now understand how i can accomplish my wanted state. Thank you!

Comment: Great job on your first stack overflow answer. One small thing that would be appreciated is a little bit of explanation instead of just giving a code dump. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do the following:

```
<div class="templatelist">
  <div class="template">
    <h2>Daily Meeting Minutes</h2>
    <div class="properties">
      <p>Sections: 5</p>
      <p>Questions: 5</p>
      <p>Tables: 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>              
<div class="menu">Burger</div>
```

keep the border and everything in the templateList class. Use the display to flex, flex-direction to row, and justify-content to space-between. I believe this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS and HTML**

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}


.templatelist {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.template {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(13.3px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(13.3px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,153,0, .5);
}

.properties {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.burger{
  font-size: 2em;
}

.options{
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
      <div class="wrapper">
        <main class="content">
            <div class="templatelist">
                <div class="template">
                  <div class="properties">
                    <div class="left">
                      <h2>Daily Meeting Minutes</h2>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p>Sections: 5</p>
                        <p>Questions: 5</p>
                        <p>Tables: 5</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="burger">
                    <p>:</p>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
      </div>
```